# React CSS background opacity

Tags: css, reactjs, background, opacity

I'm trying to add opacity to my background in CSS, but the navbar is getting the opacity and not the background.

I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

I tried to change the body tag in CSS, but the navbar is getting the opacity and not the background.

```css
body {
  background-image: url("images/fenerbahce.jpeg");
  background-size: cover;
  opacity: 50%
}

.navbar {
  padding: 20px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #939392;
  top: 0;
  background-color: #ccd0d0;
}
```

Comment: Where are you adding opacity - I can't see it anywhere. However, if you just want to change that background-color to be a bit transparent then define the 7th and 8th byte e.g. #ccd0d088

Comment: I tried to add the opacity in the css body but the navbar is getting the opacity, and If I change the 7th and 8th byte to this #ccd0d088. it still doesn't work, the page does nothing.

Comment: You don't want the whole page to have some transparency - or do you? I assumed that you just wanted that background to be a bit see through. Please could you edit your question to make the code into a runnable snippet if possible, and at least to show where you have tried adding those two extra bytes to the background color.

Answer (score 0):

Opacity is given as a decimal value. I.e. 50% is given as '0.5'

```css
body {
  background-image: url("images/fenerbahce.jpeg");
  background-size: cover;
  opacity: 0.5
}

.navbar {
  padding: 20px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #939392;
  top: 0;
  background-color: #ccd0d0;
}
```

Also, your navbar is probably part of your body. So by adding parity into the body, you're changing opacity for every component.

Comment: Oh, but how can I add the opacity on the background then? And  how can I make the navbar apart of the body or is this not possible?

Comment: Rather create a css className that has the opacity in it -> .opacityClass {opacity: 0.5}. Then add that className to the html div that holds the background.

Answer (score 0):

It seems unlikely that you want the whole body to be slightly see through (which is what you have with opacity: 50%) and nor will you want the text in your navbar to be a bit faint.

What I think you are looking for is a way to make the background of your navbar slightly see through. As it is just one color you can do this by adding a couple of bytes at the end of the hex color. Experiment to see what gives you the transparency you want.

Here's a simple example:

```html
<style>
  * {
    margin: 0;
  }
  
  body {
    background-image: url("https://picsum.photos/id/1015/1024/768");
    background-size: cover;
  }
  
  .navbar {
    padding: 20px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #939392;
    top: 0;
    background-color: #ccd0d066;
  }
</style>

<body>
  <div class="navbar">
    <ul>
      <li>link1</li>
    </ul>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help guys, @A Haworth, that was exactly what I meant :)